# Последний элемент

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Конечно же для вас это просто, но для меня javascript совсем новый язык, с которым я абсолютно не знаком. Поэтому я прошу вашей помощи.

У меня есть элемент tbody и мне нужна функция, при срабатывании которой удаляется (уничтожается) последняя строка, то есть элемент tr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#table tr:last').remove();`